# How to fix an occasional wrong answer for finding smallest number out of four randomly generated numbers

Tags: java, if-statement, random

I created some basic code for an intro to java class assignment to find the smallest number out of four randomly generated numbers from 0 to 10 inclusive using one (it has to be only one for the assignment) decision control structure, it works and gives correct answers, but occasionally it'll give the wrong answer (screenshots of incorrect answers will be attached since it may take a while to get an incorrect answer from the randomly generated numbers). I'm not sure what is causing the code to give the wrong answer on occasion.

```
        //variables
        int num1, num2, num3, num4;

        //random
        num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
        num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
        num3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
        num4 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;

        //output
        System.out.println("The four random numbers are " +
                num1 + ", " + num2 + ", " + num3 + ", and " + num4);

        //smallest number decision
        if (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3 && num1 <= num4) {
            System.out.println("The smallest number is " + num1);

        } //if end

        else if (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3 && num1 <= num4) {
            System.out.println("The smallest number is " + num2);

        } //else if end

        else if (num3 <= num1 && num3 <= num2 && num3 <= num4) {
            System.out.println("The smallest number is " + num3);
        } //else if end

        else {
            System.out.println("The smallest number is " + num4);
        } //else end
```

Incorrect Outputs

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in your second if-statement: `else if (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3 && num1 <= num4) {` should be `else if (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num3 && num2 <= num4) {`

Comment: For bonus points, figure out how to find the lowest number from a random amount of numbers.

Comment: @JacobG. Thank you so much, it's working fine now! Funny how one small mistake can be so easily missed.

Answer (score 1):

Problem (`num1 < num4`) is in the following line:

```
else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3 && num1 < num4)
```

It should be:

```
else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3 && num2 < num4)
```

**Note:** An easier way is as follows:

```
// variables
int num1, num2, num3, num4, min;

// random
num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
num2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
num3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;
num4 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 0;

// output
System.out.println("The four random numbers are " + num1 + ", " + num2 + ", " + num3 + ", and " + num4);

min = num1;
if (num2 < min) {
    min = num2;
}
if (num3 < min) {
    min = num3;
}
if (num4 < min) {
    min = num4;
}

System.out.println("The smallest number is " + min);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your current range **excludes** ten, `Math.random()` will never return `1.0` (and I would highly recommend you make that limit a variable). Next, instead of a long chain of comparisons for finding the smallest value I would invoke `Math.min(int, int)` successively. Finally, I would prefer formatted io to manual `String` concatenation. Like,

```
int limit = 11;
int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * limit);
int num2 = (int) (Math.random() * limit);
int num3 = (int) (Math.random() * limit);
int num4 = (int) (Math.random() * limit);
System.out.printf("The four random numbers are %d, %d, %d, and %d%n", 
        num1, num2, num3, num4);
System.out.printf("The smallest number is %d%n", 
        Math.min(num4, Math.min(num3, Math.min(num2, num1))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on having 10 not included (just had to change 10 to 11 and it worked)! But I have to use and if statement, it's required for the assignment. Also, I'm confused on what you mean for it will never return 1.0? I've gotten 1 as a generated number.

Comment: @Kaiju `Math.random()` will return a value between `0` and `0.999999999` (e.g. it excludes one; since you then multiply your result could be one, but the value returned by `Math.random()` explicitly excludes `1.0`). How can we be expected to know your requirements, if you do not include them in the question?

Comment: Understandable, but I did include it in my question, "...using one (it has to be only one for the assignment) decision control structure" But I understand the confusion as I didn't specify an it as an if statement, just a decision structure

Comment: @Kaiju But you did not mention that you must use **`if`**.

Comment: Yea I just edited my response that and I apologize!

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something different to avoid some repetition

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers are you planning to add?");

    int numOfNumbers = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Max number?");

    int maxNum = scan.nextInt();

    int[] nums = new int[numOfNumbers];

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand.nextInt(maxNum+1);
        System.out.println("numbers: " + nums[i]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(nums);
    System.out.println("your lowest num = " + nums[0]);
```